# collisions with images in classes corona sdk

Tags: android, ios, mobile, lua, coronasdk

How do I test for collisions in main.lua in corona sdk when the objects to test for are defined in another class?
I have an image in player class, and an image in enemy class. In main how do I detect if these images collide?

```
local function onGlobalCollision (event)

if ( event.phase == "began" ) then

print( "began: " .. event.object1.myName .. " & " .. event.object2.myName )

end

end

Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onGlobalCollision )
```

Comment: Basically I have 3 files
- main
- player
-enemy

I need to find out if a collision occurs with the images in different classes and collision detected in main.

It works easy if I put all the images in main but I wanted a OOP structure .

Answer (score 0):

It really comes down to how you've setup your classes. You might need to post more of your code. I've created this example which works as expected:

**box.lua**

```
local Box = {}
local physics = require("physics")

function Box:new()

    local box = display.newRect(math.random(0,display.contentWidth),math.random(0,display.contentHeight),100,100)
    physics.addBody(box)

    local function onTouch(event)
        if(event.phase == "began") then
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(event.target)
        elseif(event.phase == "moved") then
            event.target.x = event.x
            event.target.y = event.y
        elseif(event.phase == "ended") then
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)
        end
    end

    box:addEventListener("touch", onTouch)

    return box

end

return Box
```

**main.lua**

```
local physics = require("physics")
physics:start()
physics.setGravity(0,0)

local box1 = require("box"):new()
box1.myName = "box 1"

local box2 = require("box"):new()
box2.myName = "box 2"

local function onGlobalCollision (event)
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
        print( "began: " .. event.object1.myName .. " & " .. event.object2.myName )
    end
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onGlobalCollision )
```

I'm pretty sure you could even remove the stuff from main altogether. Make sure you have called physics.start() before anything else.